# How to select rows based on specific & conditions of a range of columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose, I have the following dataframe:

```
A B C D E F
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0.9 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 -1.95 0
0 0 0 0 2.75 0
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I want to select rows which have only zeros as well as ones (`0 & 1`) based on the columns `C, D, E and F`. For this example, the expected output is

```
 A B C D E F
 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

**How can I do this with considering a range of columns in pandas?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the test will be at least one 1 and at least one 0 in the columns C, D, E, and F but nothing other than one or zero?

Comment: @PaulBrennan, yes. You got that point what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try boolean indexing with `loc` to filter the rows:

```
c = ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
df.loc[df[c].isin([0, 1]).all(1) & df[c].eq(0).any(1) & df[c].eq(1).any(1)]
```

Result:

```
   A  B    C  D    E  F
0  1  1  1.0  0  0.0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `apply` and `loc`:

```
print(df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: sorted(x.drop_duplicates().tolist()) == [0, 1], axis=1)])
```

Output:

```
   A  B    C  D    E  F
0  1  1  1.0  0  0.0  0
```